# flex mobile project populate JSON object from spark form

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

i am building a flex mobile project. one view sends configuration values to the server. i want to send the values via JSON. how do i loop through spark form to populate an array and send the array as JSON object to the server?

```
<fx:Script>     
private function sendJSON(event:Event):void
        {
            var message:Array = new Array();
            message.push ({value:blinkGroup.selectedValue,field_name:"blink"});
            message.push ({value:macAddress.text,field_name:"macAddress"});

            var vars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            vars.data   = JSON.stringify(message);

            var req: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
            req.method      = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            req.data        = vars;
            req.url         = "http://server.com/processJSON.php"

            var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleServerResponse,false, 0, true);
            ldr.load(req);
        }
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButtonGroup id="blinkGroup" enabled="true"/>
</fx:Declarations>


<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" verticalScrollPolicy="on" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" x="355" y="10">
<s:Group>
    <s:Form id="configureForm" backgroundColor="#DCDCDC">
        <s:FormItem backgroundColor="#DCDCDC">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout />
            </s:layout>
            <s:RadioButton groupName="blinkGroup" label="Blink" value="true"/>
            <s:RadioButton groupName="blinkGroup" label="No Blink" value="false"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem label="MAC Address" backgroundColor="#DCDCDC">
            <s:TextInput id="macAddress" text="{getMacAddress()}"/>
        </s:FormItem>
        <s:FormItem backgroundColor="#DCDCDC">
            <s:layout>
                <s:HorizontalLayout />
            </s:layout>
            <s:Button label="OK" click="sendJSON(event)"/> 
            <s:Button label="Close" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('close'))"/>
        </s:FormItem>
    </s:Form>
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Settings class that has as fields the settings, then you can use the JSON.stringyfy(settings)  to make it as JSON  to do the revers you use JSON.parse (this returns a generic Object that you can use to create a Settings object)

Comment: i thought i could do a for loop over the form submission without having to set up each form field and its value.